# Ignore empty css files

Tags: css, less, gulp

I'm using gulp to generate css and min.css files from less files. However some less files has no css output (like variables.less that just define variables for import).

Is there a way to skip the empty css stream output for this files?

That's the current code that compile all less files:

```
var config = {
    lessSrc: './Content/**/*.less'
};

gulp.task('css:lessmin', function () {
    gulp.src(config.lessSrc, { base: '.' })
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

I could change the lessSrc to specific only the files I want to compile or to ignore the files I do not want to generate a css and min.css files but I have lots of situations like that, not just in the less files.

Comment: Why don't you concatenate the css files? It's faster, recommended and would solve your problem too

Comment: Because they are used in different sections of the project. I have at least 3 sections with specific css to each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good choice would be to use a filter, filtering the empty results of your globbing set:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var filter =  require('gulp-filter');
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.less')
    .pipe(filter(function(file) {
      return file.stat && file.contents.length;
    }))
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```

You pass virtual file objects to your stream, and each one of those contains contents as well as information on the file. The stat object tells you not only that is has been loaded, but also if it's a file. The contents are a buffer. With the length you can check if there's actually any content in there. Note: this will not help you with whitespaces. The file has to be **really** empty.

Comment: The filter works great if I just put it after the less() as the less file has content but the generated css doesn't.